# Hide Certain Tags on Single Post Page

Tags: posts, tags, single, template-tags

I'm trying to hide certain tags from single posts pages. I've googled and found 2 codes but both are hiding the whole post page.

I'm using a theme that needs using 2 tags ticker and slider to show the posts in the ticker and the slider. When a user goes to the post page he'll see these 2 tags and other tags, it's ok to show all tags except those 2.

Any help please.

Some of the codes I found but not the solution I'm looking for.

`function exclude_tags($tags) {
 foreach ($tags as $tag)
  switch ($tag->name) {
   case 'exclude-this-tag':
   case 'exclude-this-tag-too':
    break;
   default:
    $newtags[] = $tag;
 }
 return $newtags;
}
add_filter( 'get_the_tags', 'exclude_tags');`

`$tags = get_tags();

foreach ($tags as $tag)
 {
   if($tag->name=='the tag i want gone') continue;
   echo $tag->name.', ';
 }`

Comment: This question seems to answer your question - http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/59081/exclude-tags-from-get-the-tags

Comment: @Porter thank you for the link. The code below
<?php
    $args = array(
        'smallest'  => 15, 
        'largest'   => 15,
        'unit'      => 'px', 
        'number'    => 10,  
        'format'    => 'flat',
        'orderby'   => 'count', 
        'order'     => 'DESC',
        'include'   => $id_string,  // only include stored ids
        'exclude'   => '29, 32',
        'link'      => 'view', 
        'echo'      => true,

  );
  wp_tag_cloud( $args );
    
    ?> 
Has done the job however it's showing all tags of all posts into single. How to ask to show only related post's tags