# How to list all tags except the current tag in tag.php

Tags: tags, exclude

I'm struggling to find a way to list all my tags without the current tag showing when i'm on a tag.php page. All I have is **[this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/59081/exclude-tags-from-get-the-tags?rq=1)**, but it's not the current tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try `get_tags` with `exclude` parameter.
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_tags

`get_queried_object_id` get the tag ID from tag page.

```
$tags = get_tags(array( 
    'exclude' => get_queried_object_id(), 
)); 

$tagList = array(); 

foreach($tags as $tag) 
{ 
    $tagList[] = '<a href="'.get_tag_link($tag->term_id).'">'.$tag->name.'</a>'; 

} 
echo implode(', ', $tagList);
```

Comment: there's an error in your code, it throws me a 500 error

Comment: Can you try a dump of `get_queried_object_id()`

Comment: I don't know how to do that.

Comment: `var_dump(get_queried_object_id());` add this at the top of your page, and paste what it gives to you.

Comment: nothing at all.

Comment: Can you try the "Usage" in this page : https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_queried_object

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70670/discussion-between-pete-and-jean-remi-larcelet-prost).

Comment: OK I changed the code you gave me to this...
`$tags = get_tags(array(
    'exclude' => get_queried_object_id(),
));
foreach($tags as $tag)
{
    echo '<a href="'.get_tag_link($tag->term_id);'">'.$tag->name.'</a>';

}`

Comment: This gave me a dump of...
`object(WP_Term)#9477 (10) { ["term_id"]=> int(10) ["name"]=> string(10) "Base metal" ["slug"]=> string(10) "base-metal" ["term_group"]=> int(0) ["term_taxonomy_id"]=> int(10) ["taxonomy"]=> string(8) "post_tag" ["description"]=> string(0) "" ["parent"]=> int(0) ["count"]=> int(1) ["filter"]=> string(3) "raw" }`

Comment: Yes you updated code works now :) Great work!